# Is it possible to change the source from a pull on NGINX's RTMP module?

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I have two applications on my RTMP server:

1. /live, which receives transmissions from a series of events, and from a series of cameras (/live/{eventId}.{transmissionId}.
2. /output, which pulls from the corresponding links on /live (so /live/{eventId}.{transmissionId} gets pulled to /output/{eventId}.{transmissionId})

I'd like to be able to select which of the {transmissionId} is being pulled to /output/{eventId}. In other words, in real-time, I would like to change which of the streams of the event is being transmitted in the single output of that event (/output/{eventId}).

Is this possible?

My RTMP configuration file is the following:

```
rtmp {
    server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096; 
                application live {
                             live on;
                             record all;
                             record_suffix .flv;
                             record_path /home/ubuntu/event_videos; 
                             record_unique off;
                             wait_video on;
                             interleave on;
                             allow play 127.0.0.1;
                             deny play all;
                             access_log /var/log/nginx/access_live.log;
                }

                application output {
                        live on;
                        wait_video on;
                        interleave on;
                        record off;
                        allow play all;
                        pull rtmp://localhost/live/;
                        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_output.log;
                }

                application vod {
                        play /home/ubuntu/event_videos; 
                }
        }
}
```

Thank you